# How to crack a password protected zip file

Tags: zip, password-recovery

I recently downloaded a piece of software that came in a .ZIP archive, but the .EXE software inside of the archive had a password on it.  The website that I would have gotten the password from closed a while ago.

Because the executable is password protected it cannot be extracted.

I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium, and I use `winrar` for my archives.

So, I guess my question is **is it possible to crack a password for a file within an archive without extracting it?**

Comment: sorry, is it the software that is password protected or the archive?

Comment: @VBwhatnow "*it cannot be extracted.*" seems to indicate the archive.

Comment: you need  rar cracker, but it is a very lengthy task and you have to have lot of patience

Comment: You need some multi-threaded bruteforce cracker. But it may take a while to crack. Maybe days...weeks. You need a lot of horsepower for this.

Comment: cRARk is an excelent tool for RAR cracking.  Uses GPU to multithread attacks.  Just not sure if it supports zip files.  I do know that there is a version that supports 7-zip.

Comment: @Shiki yeah, i have an always on workstation that i can use for this.

Comment: @hydroparadise i think i willl try that! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is reputed to be the gold standard in archive extractors. Not particularly cheap, but they have a great reputation.
[Elcomsoft Advanced Archive Password Recovery.](http://www.elcomsoft.com/archpr.html)

The assumption I'm making here is that it's the archive which has the password. This is based on the fact that you say it cannot be extracted; if it were the .exe which were password protected you could extract it, you just wouldn't be able to act on the .exe. Secondly, programs inside password-protected archives are very common, and password protected .exe's are less so.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this software next time I need to access a protected archive.

Answer (score -2):

Download this [zip cracker](http://download.cnet.com/Ultimate-ZIP-Cracker/3000-2092_4-10040839.html?tag=mncol), this may help you, alternatively you can go to this site [ehow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_5998033_do-unlock-passworded-zip-file_.html), and follow the instruction.

Comment: You really should add more to this answer.  Like for instance indicate any solution is not a guaranteed solution because of the nature of simply, trying every single possible password.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound.  Most understand the "brute force" part, but every cracker has some particulars about how to set up the dictionary whether it's a string definition or an actual file it pulls from.